# Azure B2C Userflow v2.0(SignUp and SignIn) - unable to find Userinfo endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

We created an application in Azure B2C to use the OIDC implicit Grant flow. We have configured the **Userflow policy(SignIn and SignUp)** to customize the homepage layout and to get the custom claims in response. We are using Azure B2C as **External Identity Provider (IdP)** in our application. When user clicks the Login Button in our application we are redirecting the user the Azure B2C for Authentication and we are able to get the Access Token in response. But we are facing constrain in Getting the User Profile through the **UserInfo enpoint**. We have tried out both the Graph API endpoint and Azure B2C OIDC userinfo enpoint but neither of them are compatible with the Userflow policy.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, Azure AD B2C does not support the UserInfo endpoint through User-flow policy.

Right now, it is being supported only through [Custom Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userinfo-endpoint?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

You can vote for this feature on [Azure AD User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/ba84d6ca-c825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789).

A workaround is that you could integrate a Rest API to retrieve the extra claims.
See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the workaround suggested is applicable only if we need to grab some extra input from user (during sign-up) or input validation and then pass that claim to application. It will unnecessary require using "Identity Experience Framework" feature which is ideally required for custom login/signup journey and is not available under free license.

What I understand from you requirement is you need to pass built-in Azure AD attributes to application and which shall be doable by selecting extra claims from "User Flow" signup-SignIn policy. Is not there any alternative to make call to "userinfo" endpoint out of box ??  Any Microsoft expert here, please clarify.

Comment: That workaround is only applicable if you control the source - if it is a 3rd party app you are trying to integrate and it requires Userinfo, you are out of luck. Use Uservoice as per above.